# Bridging wifi to ethernet with NetworkManager

Tags: networkmanager

Newer version of the Raspberry Pi OS ship with `NetworkManager` instead of `dhcpd` running. I've seen lots of guides on how to do this with things like `dnsmasq`. But in all these guides, it's assuming `dhcpd` is running.

What I want is to share my wifi connection via my ethernet port. Clients will connect to the ethernet port and connect to the internet through the rpi's wifi.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The following worked for me:

`sudo nmcli c add con-name custom-shared-con type ethernet ifname eth0 ipv4.method shared ipv6.method ignore`

`sudo nmcli c up custom-shared-con`

This creates a DHCP server and sets up packet forwarding. I got the idea from here: https://ubuntu.com/core/docs/networkmanager/configure-shared-connections

It's so easy! There's nothing to install.

Comment: Answered your own question - Good for you!  You should "accept" this as the answer (may have to wait a day or two) so others will know that. it worked.

Comment: Worked for me - I just had to replace eth0 with end0